# XRegExp to replace Unicode characters in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, xregexp

I developed a javascript function to clean a range of Unicode characters. For example, "ñeóñú  a1.txt" => "neonu a1.txt". For this, I used a regular expression:

```
 var = new RegExp patternA ("[\\u0300-\\u036F]", "g");
 name = name.replace (patternA,'');
```

But it does not work properly in IE. If my research is correct, IE does not detect Unicode in the same way. I'm trying to make an equivalent function using the library XRegExp (http://xregexp.com/), which is compatible with all browsers, but I don't know how to write the Unicode pattern so XRegExp works in IE.

One of the failed attemps:

```
    XRegExp.replace(name,'\\u0300-\\u036F','');
```

How can I build this pattern?

Comment: [Drop support](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/01/bootstrapped-startup-saves-over-100k-by-dropping-ie/) [for IE](https://paydirtapp.com/blog/we-dont-support-ie/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value provided as the `XRegExp.replace` method's second argument should be a regular expression object, not a string. The regex can be built by the `XRegExp` or the native `RegExp` constructor. Thus, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
name = name.replace(/[\u0300-\u036F]/g, '');
// Is equivalent to:
name = XRegExp.replace(name, /[\u0300-\u036F]/g, '');
```

The following line you wrote, however, is not valid:

`var = new RegExp patternA ("[\\u0300-\\u036F]", "g");`

Instead, it should be:

`var patternA = new RegExp ("[\\u0300-\\u036F]", "g");`

I don't know if that is the source of your problem, but perhaps. For the record, IE's Unicode support is as good or better than other browsers.

XRegExp can let you identify your block by name, rather than using magic numbers. `XRegExp('[\\u0300-\\u036F]')` and `XRegExp('\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}')` are exactly equivalent. However, the marks in that block are a small subset of all combining marks. You might actually want to match something like `XRegExp('\\p{M}')`. However, note that simply removing marks like you're doing is not a safe way to remove diacritics. Generally, what you're trying to do is a bad idea and should be avoided, since it will often lead to wrong or unintelligible results.